# Bubble click event in swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-handling

I try to add a MovieClip to an existent SWF on the fly - inject an small code who do something like:

```
this.obj = new MovieClip(); // it is inside an object
obj.name = 'FLOOR';
obj.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0);
obj.graphics.drawRect(0,0,self.width, self.height);
obj.graphics.endFill();
obj.buttonMode = true;
self.addChildAt( floorLayerMC , 0); /* self is an reference for the this keyword, reference for the entire swf */
```

My question is: this SWF has many elements like images and textfields, and some of this elements has no event handler for click. I Need to find a way to "redirect" all of the events to my "FLOOR" element, using something like bubbling the event.

Of course, I can add the FLOOR in top of any elements BUT I have some elements with click handler. I can't ignore all of the elements. So my problem is:

if I click over an MovieClip with click handler, perform the original action.
if I click over an MovieClip without click handler, perform the FLOOR action.

I can't add a event handler in all of the elements.

Any Idea?

Comment: Do you have access to the SWF source?

Comment: Sure, but I can't change or break some existing behavior (like some animation).

Comment: What you can do, is change your existing click listeners in that SWF to use the capture phase (or listen with a higher priority), then stop propagation after they do their thing.   Then in your container/main application, listen on the usual bubble phase (or with a lower priority).  Then if a listener for that event already exists, it will get canceled when it's handled and your broader listener won't run

Answer (score 0):

Listen for a click on the container movieclip's own stage (the movieclip that contains the FLOOR).  In the handler method for the click event, do a hit test using hitTestPoint with the mouseX and MouseY of the container movieclip, and if the mouse is over any clickable objects, ignore the stage click.  Store all the objects that are clickable in an array to do that test.

This code is untested but it would go something like this:

```
var exemptArray:Array = [ btn_mc1, btn_mc2, btn_mc3 ];
containerMC.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMyMC);

function onClickMyMC( event:Event ):void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < exemptArray.length; i++)
    {
        if( exemptArray[i].hitTestPoint(containerMC.mouseX, containerMC.mouseY) )
        {
            // do nothing, ignore the stage click ( and let the object with the click respond )
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // respond to the stage click
        }
    }
}
```

**To build the exemptArray without knowing what objects are clickable ahead of time:
( untested but should be close enough to give you an idea ).**

```
var exemptArray:Array = buildExemptArray();

function buildExemptArray():Array
{
    var arr:Array = [];

    for(var j:int = 0; j < containerMC.numChildren; j++)
    {
        if( containerMC.getChildAt(i).hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK) )
        {
            arr.push( containerMC.getChildAt(i) );
        }
    }

     return arr:
}
```

**EDIT TO ANSWER QUESTION IN COMMENTS:**

**this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick)** will add a click event to the whole object, **children included**.

**this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick)** will add a click only to the movieclip's stage, **not its children** as well.

In as3 all movieclips have a stage property.  If you wrote on the main timeline **this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);** that would be adding a stage click to the whole swf.  But, if you wrote something like **myMC.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);** it would only add a click to that movieclip's stage (myMC's stage).  Since stage is below the display list, you can capture a click there in any movieclip.  If you don't have access to all the objects that have mouse events ahead of time, you could loop  through all the container's children and check if they have a mouseEvent with **.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK);**, create your exemptArray from that, then use the same logic above to ignore items in the exemptArray.

Comment: Wow... it is a good idea, but I have no control about the list of movieclips. I'm thinking in use the onClickMyMC in a more clean way, as my FLOOR, and add a event.stopPropagation() in all movieclips that I can control and promote a rule about add similar code in any movieclip. What is the difference between:

Comment: this.addEventListener and this.stage.addEventListener ? (this represent the entire swf).